# Understanding why length in SQL DB2 would return short results as the max character length

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I have a query that pulls the count of all last names in our DB and sorts the count by the length of the last name. This is a VARCHAR field with a max length of 120.

Some results that are a much shorter character length - 5, 6, 7, etc characters - are showing as 120. Using a RTRIM seems to get the right results, but I am confused as to why when I don't have the RTRIM why most values calculate correctly, but some don't. While I know I have the right results with the RTRIM, I just want to understand why some cases don't pull that correctly without it.

```
SELECT LENGTH(NAME_LAST), COUNT(*)
FROM database 
GROUP BY LENGTH(NAME_LAST)
ORDER BY LENGTH(NAME_LAST) DESC;
```

Comment: EDIT your question to add the Db2-server platform (Z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows), and the Db2-server version.   Also state the encoding of the column(NAME_LAST) concerned. Without the RTRIM, when the lengths are incorrect, run a query to show the hex values stored for those incorrect NAME_LAST values.  You may learn more then.

Comment: Can you have trailing spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Db2 does not trim trailing spaces unless you ask it to with e.g. `RTRIM`

```
$ db2 "create table t(v varchar(120))"
$ db2 "insert into t values space(120)"
$ db2 "select length(v) from v"

1          
-----------
        120

  1 record(s) selected.

$ db2 "select length(rtrim(v)) from v"

1          
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: well, DB2 (and other SQL DBMSes) do _add_ trailing spaces when comparing strings of un-equal lenght..  but that is a different topic.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html  "When comparing character strings of unequal lengths, the comparison is made using a logical copy of the shorter string, which is padded on the right with blanks sufficient to extend its length to that of the longer string. "

Answer (score 0):

You can have leading/trailing whitespaces or other non-printable characters.  Try concatenating quotes or some other characters around the selection of a column and it'll high light it for you.  Or as @mao suggests show the hex values

Answer (score 0):

Does this help answer your question?
"If a grouping-expression contains varying-length strings with trailing blanks, the values in the group can differ in the number of trailing blanks and might not all have the same length. In that case, a reference to grouping-expression still specifies only one value for each group, but the value for a group is chosen arbitrarily from the available set of values. Thus, the actual length of the result value is unpredictable."
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_groupbyclause.html